# Update realtime database in Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, claudiajs

I am creating a API which can update value from realtime database (Firebase). Using ClaudiaJS to create API. Basically, API will update the number of student of a class by year.

What I have done:

Realtime Database (Firebase)

```
class
 |__2015
 |    |__numberOfStudent: 50
 |__2016
      |__numberOfStudent: 60
```

Export to JSON like this:

```
{
  "class": {
    "2015": {
      "numberOfStudent": 50
    },
    "2016": {
      "numberOfStudent": 60
    }
  }
}
```

Javascript file (ClaudiaJS):

```
var ApiBuilder = require('claudia-api-builder');
api = new ApiBuilder();
module.exports = api;

var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./xxxxxxx-firebase-adminsdk-nxxxxx.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com"
});

api.post('/addmore/{year}/{number}', function (request) {
    var database = admin.database().ref('class');

    //Params
    var year = request.pathParams.year;
    var number = request.pathParams.number;

    var ref = year + '/numberOfStudent'; // '2015/numberOfStudent'

    database.update({
        ref : parseInt(number) // "2015/numberOfStudent" : 60
    });

    return 'Update successfully';

});
```

When I run the api in Postman:

> http://xxxxapi.com/addmore/2015/55

What happened: API replied 'Update successfully', but the database didn't get any update. It seems that the code *database.update()* doesn't work at all.

Any suggestion is very appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `update` call happens asynchronously, so currently the `return` happens before `update` completes.

[`update`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#update) returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), so try the following:

```
return database.update({ref : parseInt(number)})
    .then(() => {
        // Each then() should return a value or throw
        return 'Update successful';
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // handle the error however you like
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Comment: Hi @Jeff, it worked. Thanks for your quick and correct answer. ^_^

Comment: Thanks. I am getting this error: `Each then() should return a value or throw`! Not able to fix this.

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal In my example `then` returns the string `'Update successful'`. Without seeing your code it's difficult to figure out what's going on. Can you please file a new question or paste your code into a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) and link it here?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, It was the problem with return statement. I just added it without returning anything and problem solved. I suggest you should mention in your answer so that newbies like me can also take advantage.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @ShajeelAfzal! Updated the answer.

Comment: afaik, no return is needed in the catch.